# In air return flight?

Tags: wing, lift

Ok, we had a few beer.

Imaging a plane with two cockpits back to back. One Pilot flies to the destination and the other returns without turning the plane.

The question is, whether there is a profile for a wing that would create lift in both directions. Our idea was a wave form.

Is there a profile for a wing with a reverse gear?

Comment: All wing profiles provide reverse lift as well, with drag that is a lot higher though. The problem is, what will you do with the horizontal & vertical tail?

Comment: Don't forget solutions for not doubling the engines, not inverting the angle of the swept wings, not exchanging high-lift devices between edges; and solutions to block ailerons, elevators and rudder on the now leading side, to switch active end-wheel, invert air intake/exhaust for APU and air conditioning... more beers could help :-)